# Need suggestion on optimization query of multiple million of records with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

How can I optimize this query as EXT tables contain about 1.5 million records each. I have also other joins but they have relatively less than 50 records.
both EXT tables have set identity on with default setting and is P

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNumber
    , *
  FROM History
    LEFT JOIN FlattenExt1 
      ON History.ID = FlattenExt1.ExtID
    LEFT JOIN FlattenExt2 
      ON History.ID = FlattenExt2.ExtId
  ) as final
where final.RowNumber BETWEEN (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1
                          AND (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
order by final.rownumber
```

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Share your tables DDL and the execution plan as was mentioned before.

Comment: @artashes Khachatryan actually this is a piece of code only where optimization is required in terms of the left join. there are other inner joins as-well which is necessary anyhow but I have not mentioned it here.

Comment: @MonkeyD.luffy We need to see the create statements of your tables that are included in this query to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what is visible, i believe optimizer's problem here is the luck of knowing if the left joins do duplicate HISTORY.ID values, affecting ROW_NUMBER.
if the left join conditions both have join limits of 0-1 rows per history row, then do the ROW_NUMBER on history alone, get the ids, then join

```
DECLARE @page INT = 150 , @rows INT = 10
;WITH 
data AS (SELECT ID  FROM History)
,rows (page, pages, rows) AS ( SELECT @page, CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS float)/@page), COUNT(*) FROM data )
SELECT * FROM history INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP (@rows) rowNumber,page, pages, rows,ID 
          FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID  ASC ) rowNumber, * FROM rows, data ) pagination
          WHERE rowNumber > (@page-1) * @rows
          order by rowNumber
    )historypageids ON history.ID = historypageids
LEFT JOIN FlattenExt1 ON History.ID = FlattenExt1.ExtID
LEFT JOIN FlattenExt2 ON History.ID = FlattenExt2.ExtId
```

Comment: this suggestion lead me to heavily optimized query time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION (generic SQL Server).

The following only works for SQL Server 2012+.

If you don't need the `row_number()` value, I would suggest:

```
 SELECT . . .
 FROM History h LEFT JOIN
      FlattenExt1 f1
      ON h.ID = f1.ExtID LEFT JOIN
      FlattenExt2 f2
      ON h.ID = f2.ExtId                                                           
 ORDER BY h.ID
 OFFSET (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
 FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS;
```

This should be able to take advantage of an index on `History(ID)`, `FlattenExt1(ExtId)`, `FlattenExt2(ExtId)`.

Comment: i am restricted to use SQL2008R only –

Comment: @MonkeyD.luffy, I added the version-specific tag to your question.